# How to update sfUserProfile after the completion of a separate module? postSave() not working

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, dql

I have a registration form that includes sfRegistration and sfProfile, which after completion, get's redirected to another form - to determine the user's corporation and is a seperate module.  The sfProfile includes a field from the corporation module... the corporate_id.  But since the corporate_id is not part of the profile, it does not get included at registration time.  Here's the question, after completion of the corporation module, what is the best way to update the user's profile with the corporate_id of the newly completed corporation module?  I tried this:

```
public function postSave()
{
$corpId = $this->form->getId();
$logged_user_id = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getId();
Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('sf_guard_user_profile p')
->set('p.corporate_id', $corpId)
->where('p.user_id' == $logged_user_id )
->execute();
}
```

placed into the action of the company module, but it is not updating the profile with the company_id.

Suggestions?

UPDATE - per request, here is the information requested: (my >>lib>form>>doctrine>>CorporationForm.class.php is empty... I was trying my functions in the actions class... which may be the issue).  Just to clarify, I just need to update the user's profile with the newly created corporate_id after the user completes the corporation module.
And my schema:

```
sfGuardUser:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    first_name: string(255)
    last_name: string(255)
    email_address:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    username:
      type: string(128)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    algorithm:
      type: string(128)
      default: sha1
      notnull: true
    salt: string(128)
    password: string(128)
    is_active:
      type: boolean
      default: 1
    is_super_admin:
      type: boolean
      default: false
    last_login:
      type: timestamp
  indexes:
    is_active_idx:
      fields: [is_active]
  relations:
    Groups:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: user_id
      foreign: group_id
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      foreignAlias: Users
    Permissions:
      class: sfGuardPermission
      local: user_id
      foreign: permission_id
      refClass: sfGuardUserPermission
      foreignAlias: Users

sfGuardUserProfile:
 actAs:            { Timestampable: ~ }
 columns:
  id: { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
  user_id: { type: integer }
  corporate_id: { type: integer }
  type_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  prefix_id: { type: integer }
  middle_name: { type: string(55) }
  suffix_id: { type: integer }
  phone: { type: string(55), notnull: true }
  home_address_line_one: { type: string }
  home_address_line_two: { type: string }
  home_city: { type: string }
  state_id: { type: integer }
  home_zip: { type: integer } 
 relations:
  User: { class: sfGuardUser, local: user_id, foreign: id, type: one, foreignType: one,     foreignAlias: Profile }
  Type: { local: type_id, foreign: id, type: one, foreignAlias: Types } 
  Prefix: { local: prefix_id, foreign: id, type: one, foreignAlias: Prefixs } 
  Suffix: { local: suffix_id, foreign: id, type: one, foreignAlias: Suffixs }   
  State:  { local: state_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: States }  
  Corporation: { local: corporate_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Corporations }

Corporation:
  columns:
   id:             { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true,    unique: true }
   user_id:        { type: integer }
   name:           { type: string(55), notnull: true }
   address_line1:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }
   address_line2:   { type: string(255), notnull: true }
   city:           { type: string(25), notnull: true }
   state_id:       { type: integer, notnull: true }
   zip:            { type: string(25), notnull: true }
   phone:          { type: string(25), notnull: true }
   email:          { type: string(100), notnull: true }
   website:        { type: string(100) }
   logo:           { type: string(255) }
  relations:
    User: { class: sfGuardUser, local: user_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the ->save();

```
    public function setId() 
  {
        $user_id = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
        $corp_id = 1;
        $user_profile = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUserProfile')->findOneByUserId($user_id);
        $user_profile->setCorporateId($corp_id)->save();
   }

  protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {            
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        self::setId();        
        $corporation = $form->save();    
        $this->redirect('dashboard/index');      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form:

```
public function  doUpdateObject($values)
  {

   parent::doUpdateObject($values);
   $this->getObject()->setCorporateId(your value);

}
```

For example
//apps/frontend/yourmodule/action.class.php

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
    {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {

       $corporation = $form->save();
       $user_id=$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
       $profile = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUserProfile')->findOneByUserId($user_id);
       $profile->setCorporateId('your value');
```

Comment: I'm just a beginner (if you couldn't already tell)... can you please elaborate a little?  Do I place the function in my action class or my table class of the corporate module?  Then, when do I call the function, and on what?  Do I keep my postsave() method or get rid of it altogether?  Thanks for your patience with me...

Comment: In your form lib/form/doctrine/NameForm.class.php using  **public function  doUpdateObject($values)** you can update some data in your table.Can you post code of your form , schema?[some example](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/96345/)

Comment: denys281: thank you for the response; I was losing hope.  I've updated my question with the information you requested.  ...and thanks again for helping this newbie out.  ...it's starting to click.  :)

Comment: Ок, you want that after user post form , you want update value corporate_id in sfGuardUserProfile?

Comment: It is very simple;-) you have action class in your apps/frontend/modules/you module..update my answer.

Comment: hmmm.... that doesn't seem to work.  My logs indicate that the sfGuardUserProfile table is not even being accessed.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Update: these statements works: $user_profile = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUserProfile')->findOneByUserId($user_id)->getMiddleName; echo $user_profile.  These statements do not: $user_profile = doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUserProfile')->findOneByUserId($user_id); $user_profile->getMiddleName(); echo $user_profile; In this last example, it returns the sfGuardUser username no matter which field I ask it to get.  Which makes no sense to me.  So, obviously I cannot set any field b/c it is trying to set a field in the sfGuardUser table that doesn't exist.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Got it figured out... see "Answer" in original post.  ...just missing the ->save()

Comment: Ooops, I forget it in answer :)